# Solving a simple quadratic equation : $40x+3 = (x+14)(x+3)+(x+1)$

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers

I have the equation from one of the textbooks (which is, I know, very simple):

$40x+3 = (x+14)(x+3)+(x+1)$. My first approach to the solution is as follows

$$\begin{align*}
40x+3&=x^{2} +14x +3x +42 +x +1 \\[0.1cm]
40x+3 &= x^{2} +18x +43\\[0.1cm]
40x &= x^{2} +18x + 40 \\[0.1cm]
0 &= x^{2} -22x +40 \\[0.1cm]
0 &= (x-2)(x-20)
\end{align*}$$

and it follows that $x_{1} = 2$ and $x_{2} = 20$ (these are also the solutions in the textbook).
The second approach:

$$\begin{align*}
40x+3&=x^{2} +14x +3x +42 +x +1 \\[0.1cm]
 40x+3 &= x^{2} +18x +43\\[0.1cm]
 40x &= x^{2} +18x +40 \\[0.1cm]
22x  &= x^{2} + 40 \\[0.1cm]
-x^{2} +22x -40 &= 0 \\[0.1cm]
- (x-2)(x-20)&= 0
\end{align*}$$

Why do I get $- (x-2)(x-20)$ with the second approach, I should get the same answer as before. Where is the mistake?

Comment: If $a=0$ then $-a=0$

Comment: You *are* getting the same answer as before. There is no mistake.

Comment: You will get the same roots from both approaches. If you want the second approach to look the same, you can divide both sides of your equation by $-1$ but it is not necessary to answer the question.

Comment: Um... you do get the same answers.   $(x-2)(x-20) = 0 \iff -(x-0)(x-20)=0$ because $k=0 \iff -k = 0$.   Note:  neither $(x-2)(x-20) = 0$ nor $-(x-2)(x-20)$ are *answers*; they are both the last step before *getting* the answers and they both get the answer $\{2, 20\}$.  Although they are different *steps* on the way to an answer there is no reason different steps won't both give the same answers (as these certainly do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negatives can trip people up easily at first:

You have reduced things to $0 = x^{2} -22x + 40 = (x-2)(x-20)$

Note that by subtracting from both sides:

$(x-2)(x-20)= 0$

$(x-2)(x-20)-(x-2)(x-20) = 0 -(x-2)(x-20)$

$ \Rightarrow 0=-(x-2)(x-20)$

So it is equivalent to solve $0=-(x-2)(x-20)$ and $0=(x-2)(x-20)$.

This kind of situation arises often, you just have to get used to it.

Further, note:

$(x-2)(x-20)= 0$

$(-1)(2-x)(-1)(20-x)= 0$

$(2-x)(20-x)= 0$

So it is equivalent to solve $0=(x-2)(x-20)$ and $0=(2-x)(20-x)$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, only one (probably silly) question:  For example, if I insert 5 in the polynomials I get $5^{2} -22 \times 5 +40= -45$ and in the second one, I get $(-5)^{2} + 22 \times 5 -40 =95$, but that is not the same.

Comment: Not a silly question! It gets to the _root_ of the matter. First, the positive and negative versions of the equations are actually different - they are mirror images about the y-axis. However, their *roots* - where they cross zero - are the same. That's key. Second, if you plug in any other non-root value of x, you get the non-zero answers, positive or negative according to which equation you use. Evaluate x=5 or x=6 or any non-root in both equations and you'll see what I mean. Graph it too to better understand these behaviors.

Comment: Best of all, construct a handful of quadratics, cubics etc. by graphing only the lines that make them (the factors), imagine where they must be zero, where they are positive or negative, etc. This will make it very clear what the roots do, how to shift curves, etc.

Comment: O, I see! Thank you very much!